# __NSArrayI rangeOfCharacterFromSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have following NSMutableArray.

```
 NSLog(@"vacc_name:%@",vaccScheduleArray_);
```

output is :

```
vacc_name:(
        (
        "Hepatitis B (HepB)"
    ),
        (
        "Hepatitis B (HepB)  2nd"
    ),
        (
        "Hepatitis B (HepB)  2nd"
    ),
        (
        "Rotavirus 1st"
    ),
        (
        "Rotavirus 2nd"
    ),
        (
        "Diphtheria, pertussis,and tetanus DTaP"
    )
```

and my uitableview code is:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    scheduleTableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyScheduleCell"];
    if (!cell)
    {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"scheduleTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyScheduleCell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyScheduleCell"];
    }

    cell.vaccNameLabel.text=[vaccScheduleArray_ objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"vaccine name:%@",cell.vaccNameLabel.text);

    return cell;
}
```

i got this error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175f3230'`

Comment: [[vaccScheduleArray_ objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: @KiritModi not working,i use it...

Comment: As above array inside array.

Comment: @KiritModi it always crash on index 5...i donot know this part...

Comment: show the code of numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: @KiritModi return vaccScheduleArray_.count...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your App is Crash on Index 5 Because of comma separator. Index 5 have an Array and It contains not only one object but Three object in it.

```
(
    "Diphtheria, 
     pertussis,
     and tetanus DTaP"
)
```

So that you take only 0 index remaining is not taken.

Replace comma (,) separator with (.) separator in this object it working fine.

Comment: Please rethink your answer. It's complete nonsense. Object five is an array (like all the other objects) containing a single string. And that string can contain any characters, including commas. It's still one string.

Answer (score 0):

Your array vaccScheduleArray_ (unusual name, you should seriously adopt common naming conventions) is not an array of six strings. It is an array of six arrays, each containing a single string. So you are trying to set the text of a label to an NSArray.

Here's the giveaway for future cases: The crash clearly happens because an NSString method is sent to an NSArray object. So at some point you are giving an NSArray to someone who expects an NSString. And then the question is "where"?

Comment: its same to your answer, But you are not capable to understand above answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *vaccineNameArray = [vaccScheduleArray_ objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.vaccNameLabel.text = vaccineNameArray[0];
```

The issue is, you are assigning an array to `label's`, `text` property.